# Plot a binary tree in R from a list

Tags: r

I have a list that I would like to plot it into a tree.
This is what the list looks like:

```
> tree_list
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1]  2  9 10

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 5 8

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 3 4 6


[[2]]
[1] 7
```

The integers 1:10 are the nodes of the tree. The [[1]] or [[2]] denotes left or right to the tree.
Thanks!

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Any chance of using R tree functions to directly generate the tree for you?

Comment: The data comes from a recursion algorithm I wrote. So far, I have only been plotting the tree by hand. This above is is only 3-depth, so it hasn't called a problem. But I will eventually try to plot more depth and many more nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i've written a very ugly function that seems to do it. There must be a better way. Here I basically create a fake "tree" object. Then i try to use the default `plot.tree` and `text.tree` from `library(tree)`. Turns out I had to add in a bunch of crazy values and attributes to be convincing enough to run without error. And i'm not even sure this is the behavior you want.

```
library(tree)
gettree<-function(tree_list) {
    flatten<-function(x, node=1) {
        if(is.list(x)) {
            sub<-do.call(rbind, 
               lapply(1:2, function(i) flatten(x[[i]], node=node*2+i-1) ))
            rbind(data.frame(name=paste("split",node), nodeid=node,
               N=sum(as.numeric(sub$n)), n=0, vals=NA), sub)
        } else {
            data.frame(name="<leaf>", nodeid=node, N=0, n=length(x), vals=I(list(x)))
        }
    }
    ff<-flatten(tree_list)
    is.leaf <- grepl("<leaf>",ff$name)
    df<-data.frame(
        var=ff$name,
        n=pmax(ff$N,ff$n), dev=ff$n,
        yval=factor(sapply(ff$vals, paste, collapse=","))
    )
    df$splits<-matrix(cbind(ifelse(!is.leaf, "","left"), 
        ifelse(!is.leaf, "","right")), ncol=2,
        dimnames=list(NULL, c("cutleft","cutright")))
    rownames(df)<-ff$nodeid
    whmx <- do.call(rbind, mapply(cbind, seq_along(ff$vals), ff$vals))
    y<-factor(whmx[!is.na(whmx[,2]),2])
    wh<-as.numeric(whmx[!is.na(whmx[,2]),1])
    yf<-factor(df$yval)
    yprob <- matrix(0, ncol=nlevels(yf), nrow=length(yf))
    yprob[cbind(seq_along(yf), as.numeric(yf))]<-1
    df$yprob <- yprob
    structure(list(frame=df,y=y, where=wh),  class="tree", ylevels=levels(yf))
}
```

Once we've defined that function, we can run it with your data.

```
tree_list<-list(list(list(c(2,9,10), c(5,8)), c(1,3,4,6)), 7)

mt<-gettree(tree_list)

plot(mt, type="uniform")
text(mt, splits=F)
```

and that makes this plot

[image: binary tree visualization]

It's still quite rough around the edges, but if you're really interested perhaps you could clean it up.

Comment: Using your data structure for the tree, is there a syntax to compute the level of the tree? This tree has level (or height) 3. The command length() does not work here. It seems to always give the answer 3....

Comment: There is an un-exported function called `tree.depth` in the `tree` package that you could use. For example: `tree:::tree.depth(as.numeric(rownames(mt$frame)))`. I might make a nicer wrapper for that if you plan to use it often.

Comment: Interesting! I suppose the depth of the tree would be max(tree:::tree.depth(as.numeric(rownames(mt$frame)))). I plan to use this often for checking the depth of the tree during the recursion.

Comment: plot(mt, type="uniform")
    text(mt, splits=F, label = 'n', all = T)
I used the above function to plot the tree so that all the nodes label imply how many elements in it. The label on the nodes are correct. However the labels on the inner nodes are incorrect. I am not sure which part of your function to change, can you help me with that? thanks!

Comment: @user2498497 I'd need to see a reproducible example to be able to help. I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I plotted the tree using the following code:tree_list<-list(list(list(c(2,9,10), c(5,8)), c(1,3,4,6)), 7)
mt<-gettree(tree_list)
plot(mt, type="uniform")
text(mt, splits=F, label = 'n', all = T)
Supposedly, at the top of each node, the labels should be the number of the child leaves. However, the tree function you constructed does not seem to work so. I can post a figure in the answer box.